# Why is the ellipsis floating at center of the string?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I ran into this problem while trying to truncate my text with an ellipsis. I'm using Tailwind CSS classes to achieve this.

##### Description:

- The string should be truncated like `John D...` if it's too long, the ellipsis should be aligned at the bottom of the string.

[image: screenshot]

- But instead, the ellipsis is floating in the middle of the string like this:

[image: screenshot]

- I'm using `'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif` font here. I tried changing to another default fonts but it's still behave in the same way.

##### Here's the code I use to truncate the text:

```
.truncate {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

**JSX:**

```
<div className="rounded-t opacity-80 z-10 flex items-center absolute max-w-[17ch] text-black bg-white py-px px-2 bottom-0 right-4 transform-3d">
   <Icon />
   <p className='truncate mb-0'>{attendeeName}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `...` may be occurring due to some other dependency/class like if you have `item-center` class somewhere in the div wrapping this text.

> Assuming this is the code and had no dependency

Otherwise, you don't need to add any additional CSS and `!important`. Just add `truncate text-elipsis` class to the text.

Below is the implementation where I had shown the text-elipsis functionality

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-5 space-y-4">
  <div class="max-w-[5rem] bg-slate-200">
   <Icon />
   <p class='truncate text-ellipsis mb-0'>attendeeName</p>
</div>
<div class="max-w-[8rem] bg-slate-200">
   <Icon />
   <p class='truncate text-ellipsis mb-0'>attendeeName</p>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see if you use it normally then the `...` appears at the bottom. So try to check the complete code again.

#### Edit after discussion with presenter

I had added the flex class in a span and removed some unnecessary classes.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="transform-3d bottom-0 right-4 z-10 max-w-[17ch] rounded-t bg-red-300 py-px px-2 text-black opacity-80">
  <span class="flex flex-row space-x-2">
    <img src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week5-triangle.png" class="h-6 w-6" />
    <p class="mb-0 truncate text-ellipsis">attendeeName is very short</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast support Mohit! It's true that I have an `items-center` class at the wrapping div, but that's to center align the Icon and the p tag. I tried to leave it out but it doesn't work. And I'm using Tailwind so the `!important` is already included when I add the `truncate` class.

Comment: Just share the complete code, so that I can figure out. Or you can inspect the `...` element on chrome and check out it classes. pLease upvote my answer if this helps

Comment: Sure, I just updated the complete code in my question. I tried to inspect the `...` but it just a `p` tag with those classes above.

Comment: I had edited my answer , please check

Comment: I followed your code above but it still doesn't work, the text doesn't truncate anymore. Please check this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r1PUNS1_oXPk

Comment: Now I can only find the mistake when you share the complete code. Try to debug it